# Terminal emulator with good plugin support?

Tags: linux, plugins, terminal

Is there any good linux terminal emulator that supports plugins?

What I am after:

- Open source
- Being able to highlight and color text fragments
- Being able to tweak the GUI (create popup windows, present menus and buttons integrated with the text display -- for instance to open the man page in a floating window when clicking on a command name)
- Being able to write plugins in a number of languages (Ruby preferred)

Cheers!

Comment: Off-tpic for SO;  belongs on superuser.com

Answer (score 0):

All that I found:

- [termit](https://github.com/nonstop/termit/wiki/) - extensible via lua
- [rxvt-unicode](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Urxvt) - extensible via perl